# Not sure how to write out Mouse.Hover inside if statement

Tags: c#, webforms

I have few labels which I have tagged with `iconName` and used `foreach` to hide them, which works fine.
Now I would like to run an if statement, so that when the mouse hovers over the icons, the `iconName` shows. But I don't know how to write it.

```
        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            
            foreach (Label iconName in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
            {
                if (iconName.Visible)
                {
                    iconName.Hide(); // this works fine 
                }

                if (iconName.MouseHover += new EventHandler()) // This line I don't know how to make it work
                {
                   
                    iconName.Show(); 

                }

            }
        }
```

P.S. I don't understand the `+=` or `-=` on the syntax highlighted either? Does it mean which mouse button is correct if a user has the right mouse button switched?

Comment: Does your C# book not discuss and explain event handlers and how to use them? "If" is not "when".

Comment: Uh... `MouseHover` is an event, what do you think you are trying to check with that `if`? In Winforms you handle all such interaction via callbacks, you don't check repeatedly in a loop

Comment: I don't have a C# book, I watched tutorial videos but not came across how to use. Second part I don't understand, why I am unable to check this with if? I get your point, it is an event which seems it is another piece to the language, but why can I not use if to check if a certain condition is true in C#? for example, if mouse.hover is true/false, C# can't tell? that seems odd to me...

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
iconName.MouseHover += new EventHandler((object iconName, EventArgs e) => { 
    ((Label)iconName).Show(); 
});
```

To put the event handler code in-line, however this would not work as the mouseover event would not fire for the hidden label.

If you put the labels inside panels (invisible containers) then you could use something like;

```
foreach (Panel p in this.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
{
    foreach (Label iconName in p.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    {
        iconName.Hide(); 
    }
    p.MouseHover += new EventHandler((object p, EventArgs e) => {
        foreach (Label iconName in ((Panel)p).Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {
            iconName.Show();
        }
    });
}
```

I assume that you want the label to disappear after you move off it, you would need to add a MouseLeave event to panel to hide the label again after the mouse moves out of the panel area